# Show soft keyboard in AlertDialog with a WebView inside (Android)

Tags: android, webview, android-alertdialog, android-softkeyboard

In my Android app I create an `AlertDialog` that has a `WebView` inside. The `WebView` loads a webpage that requires the user to log in. However, when I click on text fields in the `WebView`, soft keyboard does not appear. I am aware of the issue in general ([Android: Issue 7189](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7189)); however, in my case the suggested solution does not seem to work since I use an external website, and not just a simple HTML form.

The perfect solution would be if the keyboard appeared when the user clicked on the website's text fields. However, having the keyboard appear together with the`AlertDialog` would also work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It seems that the best solution is to simply create a custom dialog. Custom dialogs do not appear to have the soft keyboard bug at all (it shows up exactly when it has to). Here's some basic code:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
dialog.setTitle("My great title");
dialog.setCancelable(true);

dialog.show();
dialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.icon);

WebView vw = (WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.wv);
```

Comment: please share your complete code. I am having same problem but I am not loading my webview in dialog. I am launching it in an Activity and pressing on any text field is not showing keyboard. help me

Comment: Thanks!!! for me the AlertDialog was the issue, when changed to Dialog, it works!! tried all possible workarounds with AlertDialog, focus, viewport, touch listeners, custom webview classes etc...

Comment: @AZ_ if you're not using a dialog, how is it the same problem?

Comment: @eis This bug has been fixed by Google. It's 6 years old post so I don't even have slight idea :p

Answer (score 5):

There much better solution (with AlertDialog).

1. Extend WebView class.

   ```
   public static class LocalWebView extends WebView {
       public LocalWebView(Context context) {
           super(context);
       }

       public LocalWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
           super(context, attrs);
       }

       public LocalWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
           super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
       }

       @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
       public LocalWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
           super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
      }

       public LocalWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, boolean privateBrowsing) {
           super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, privateBrowsing);
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
           return true;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use this LocalWebView instead of origin WebView in layout that you set to AlertDialog as content view.

Comment: Thanks, it works. You can also just use diectly: `new WebView(this){
            @Override
            public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
                return true;
            }
        };`

Comment: 6 years later and apparently this is still an issue with WebView.. no keyboard when clicking on an input field. Extending onCheckIsTextEditor() fixed it for me too

Answer (score 0):

If it's still relevant, for me the problem was related to an immersive dialog + webview.

I've override the dialog **show** method to  achieve immersive by setting a flag - NOT FOCUS on the dialog window, once I removed it I lost the immersivnes but now my web dialog pops uo the keyboard...