# android webview virtualkey board

Tags: android

I have a URL where User can Input in a Field.

When I open that URL with the Android Browser and click in the Field
 the Virtual Keyboard pops up.
 When I open the same URL with my WebView and click in the Field the
 Virtual Keyboard does NOT appear?!

What Do I have to do?
 my code is below

LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(InviteFriends.this);
            textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.link, null);

```
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(InviteFriends.this);
        builder.setTitle("Web view");
        builder.setView(textEntryView);

        wvLink = (WebView) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.wv);


        wvLink.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wvLink.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        wvLink.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

        wvLink.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });





        builder.setNegativeButton("oK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(
                            DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) { 
                        try {
                            if (type == 0) {


                              }

                        } catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                    }
                });


        alert = builder.create();

        alert.show();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you are showing that webpage in an `AlertDialog`, right? Well, I just had that problem [a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563957/show-soft-keyboard-in-alertdialog-with-a-webview-inside-android), and in the end I solved it by creating a custom `Dialog`. Custom `Dialog` is not affected by the `WebView` [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7189), and the `AlertDialog` is. So your solution would look sth like this:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Web view");
dialog.setCancelable(true);

dialog.show();

WebView vw = (WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.wv);
```

You would also need to define layout for the dialog with a `WebView` and a `Button` inside.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the same problem discussed at [WebView textarea doesn't pop up the keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460915/webview-textarea-doesnt-pop-up-the-keyboard)

The solution appears to be :

> The problem was that webview wasn't
>   getting focus when it was loaded hence
>   using
>
> ```
> webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
> ```
>
> solved the prblem.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: This may be a 'known bug' described here http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7189, there are some hacks on that thread that may help