# Show keyboard on autofocus in webview

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I have an android app that's using webview.
Several forms I'm using have autofocus on the first element.
What I want is for the relevant keyboard to display when the form is loaded. The code in the activity is:

```
public class MyActivity extends DroidGap {
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //load the main app
    loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}

@Override
public void init() {
    final String version = getVersion();
    CordovaWebView webView = new CordovaWebView(this);
    init(webView, new CordovaWebViewClient(this, webView) {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            boolean redirected = false;
            //If the page you're accessing is the login page
            if (url.endsWith("/Login")) {
                //redirect to root page with query string
                appView.loadUrl(url + "?version=" + version));
                redirected = true;
            }

            return redirected;
        }
    }, new CordovaChromeClient(this, webView));
    }
}
```

Basically what is happening in the code above the index page of the app is loaded. When I click on the login button the app version is appended to the url that is loaded (for reasons unrelated) and the login page is displayed.
When the page loads I can see the cursor inside the field but the keyboard won't display until I have pressed on the field.

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460915/webview-textarea-doesnt-pop-up-the-keyboard) but couldn't figure out how to apply the answers.
Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using

```
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    // Display the keyboard automatically when relevant
                    if (view.getTitle().equals("Login")) {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.showSoftInput(view, 0);
                    }
                }
```